# lost FreeBSD efi loader after upgrading windows 10

Tags: partition, freebsd, boot-loader, uefi

How to return option to load FreeBSD, after it was lost next to upgrading windows 10.
I use uefi-FreeBSD10, and didn't created another one ESP.

Comment: I'm surprised that's all you lost - I didn't know there was a FreeBSD > Windows 10.1 upgrade path. I would think there must have been at least 2 or 3 intermediate service pack installations involved.

Comment: I don't get what are you talking about. I have #1 - efi partition, #2 - ntfs (windows) #[4-9] - / (freebsd). So after upgrading windows -> #1 (efi) partition was rewrited that's why I lost FreeBSD bootloader.

Comment: I'd like to second @mikeserv's pin but you're likely just lacking an NVRAM entry that would point to some sane bootloader/bootmanager (these rather don't include windows' one); check what `efibootmgr` would tell.